# notation lcm of a set of numbers

Tags: notation, gcd-and-lcm

Let's assume set S = (a,b,c,d,e).

I'm looking for a correct notation of the least common multiple (lcm) of S.

Cause S does have a lot of elements I want to avoid lcm{a,b,c,d,e}. Is lcm{S} also a correct notation?

Answer (score 4):

I would write $\operatorname{LCM}(S)$ or $\operatorname{lcm}(S)$, or possibly $\operatorname{lcm}S$.

The way you wrote it appears incorrect, as $\{S\}$ is a *set* with a single element $S$. (Never mind that $S$ itself is a set, or rather a $5$-tuple as you've used parentheses intead of braces.) In contrast, $(S)$ usually means just $S$, instead of the $1$-tuple containing $S$.

I think both $\operatorname{LCM}(a,b,c,d,e)$ and $\operatorname{LCM}\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ are fine (not considering the excessive length that you want to avoid). It makes sense to take the LCM of a tuple or a set or a multiset of numbers.

Comment: thx. for your answer!